# Is it possible to disable notifications sound on do not disturb mode?

Tags: sound, notifications

In do not disturb mode, notifications don't appear but they **do sound**

Is there anyway to disable their sound too?

Comment: What apps are you experiencing this with? We can't seem to reproduce it.

Comment: @LewisGoddard whatsie. Actually, if I try to disable its notifications' sound from the settings, it still sounds.

Answer (score 1):

In *System Settings>Notifications* you can set if notifications play sound. :)

Comment: I know it, but I want them to play sound every time except in case that do not disturb mode is enabled, and there is no setting for it